# Ruby: syntax error at or near "$1" using PG Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

I am getting error while executing the statement

res = conn.exec_params('CREATE DATABASE $1',[table_name])

while if i use this statement
select statement 'SELECT * FROM pg_database WHERE datname = $1' this statement is sucessfull.

any idea what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: What're you trying to achieve? Allowing the application to create arbitrary *databases* seems like an unusual case.

Comment: It's not in our case the script creates some sample database for testing purposes. Any solution to the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to create the testing databases in your code? Why can't you use Rails defaults to create the test databases for you?

Comment: Don't know what's wrong, but two things I would try: (1) Put a semicolon after the `$1`, (2) Instead of making `exec_params` to insert the database name, I would do it using Ruby string interpolation.... Off-topic question: Why do you call the variable `table_name`, when it's not the name of a table, but a database?